# bool variable not getting set to true C#

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

I have a boolean which is set to false when being declared,

```
public bool row1 = false;
```

However, when I run some code in order to set the boolean to true, it doesn't seem to be wokring,

```
if (currentBox.BackColor == cardColour)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Draw a Card.");
}
else if (currentBox.BackColor != cardColour)
{
    row = true;
}
```

The above code is the method body of a method which is  being called in a picturebox mouse click event method (using row1 in the parameters when calling the method). At its current state, it's saying it's false when it should be set to true.

Here is the code which is calling the method.

```
private void rowOne_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    AllowTake(row1, currentCardPictureBox, Color.White, sender, e);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the `row` parameter by ref: `row1` is a separate local variable and its value is not used outside the method.

```
void MakeTrue(bool flag) {
    flag = true;
}

//Calling code:
bool myFlag = false;
MakeTrue(myFlag);
```

After `MakeTrue` is called the value of `myFlag` doesn't change. Its value is used to initialize a `flag` argument in `MakeTrue` method and that's it. After that whatever you do to `flag` won't affect the value of `myFlag`.

Now, if you do this:

```
void MakeTrue(ref bool flag) {
    flag = true;
}

//Calling code:
bool myFlag = false;
MakeTrue(ref myFlag);
```

you will get the desired (in your case) behavior: `flag` will be just an *alias* for `myFlag` variable and whatever you assign to it will become the value of `myFlag`.

Some links to read:

- [Passing parameters (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Parameters passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)
- [Why `ref` and `out` in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336814.aspx).